# React-Router v4 - pass parameters to withRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This code works fine:

```
const LinkButton = withRouter(({ history }) => (

  <ListItem button onClick={() => history.push('/url1')}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <ListIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="name1" />
  </ListItem>
))
```

Now I try to map array to the same component and get error:

```
const navItems = [{ name: 'name1', url: '/url1' }, { name: 'name2', url: '/url2' }];



 const items = navItems.map(
  item => withRouter(({ history }) => (

    <ListItem button onClick={() => history.push(item.url)}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <ListIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
    </ListItem>
  ))()
);
```

And the error text: TypeError: Cannot read property 'wrappedComponentRef' of undefined.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`withRouter` is a high-order component which returns a **component class**  (`MyComponent` ) NOT **component instance** (`<MyComponent />` ) .

Also , `LinkButton` is hard coded ; it does not accept props for items.

Then, you need to update to following :

```
let LinkButton = ({ history, ...item }) => (

  <ListItem button onClick={() => history.push(item.url)}>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <ListIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
  </ListItem>
);

LinkButton = withRouter(LinkButton);
```

Now , the loop should be :

```
navItems.map(item => <LinkButton {...item} key={item.name} />);
```